# How to load local html file into UIWebView with swift4.2

Tags: html, swift

How to load local html file into UIWebView using swift4.2. And how to drag html to the xcode?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "local"?

Comment: one added to the xcode

Comment: Not related to your question but you should use `WKWebView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In apps that run in iOS 8 and later, use the WKWebView class instead of using UIWebView.

```
  import WebKit

 @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   let localFilePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "document_terms_of_use", withExtension: "html")
   let request = URLRequest(url: localFilePath!)
webView.load(request as URLRequest)
}
```

Comment: You should use `URLRequest` initializer instead of casting to it. Just drop the NS prefix. If you need a mutable request just declare `URLRequest` as `var`